# Equation of a line that intersects two lines in a segment of length $2$

Tags: analytic-geometry

How can I find the line that passes through the point $(1,1)$ and intersects the lines $x+y=0$ and $x-y-1=0$ in a segment of length $2$?

I've tried assuming that we know the points of the intersections and then find the conditions, but an equation of the fourth degree appeared.
So can anybody suggest any other idea?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", "Find", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: 1. Write general equation of line passing through the point $(1,1)$: $y-1=k(x-1)$. 2. Find intersection points of this line with two given lines in terms of $k$. 3. Write equation that distance between intersection point is $2$: $(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=2^2$. 4. Solve for $k$.

Comment: I suppose answer cannot be expressed in more easy form than answer of fourth degree equation. Check in Wolfram Alpha or something else.

Comment: [The answers are ugly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3m%5E4%2B6m%5E3-18m%5E2%2B6m-5%3D0), it looks like.

Comment: One more equation to $eq=\{ x_1+y_1=0, x_2-y_2-1=0,(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2=2^2, (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)=m \}$

Answer (score 0):

Let the direction vector of the line passing through $(1,1)$ be the unit vector $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta) ) $, then the parametric equation of the line is

$ P = (1, 1) + t (\cos(\theta) , \sin(\theta) ) = (1 + t \cos(\theta) , 1 + t \sin(\theta) ) $

where $t $ is the parameter, $t \in \mathbb{R} $

Plug in the point $P$ into the two lines given. For the first line we have

$ 2 + t (\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) ) = 0 $

So, $ t_1 = \dfrac{-2}{ \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) } $

For the second line, we get

$ t_2( \cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) ) - 1 = 0 $

So

$ t_2 = \dfrac{1}{ \cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) } $

The distance between the two points of intersection is $| t_1 - t_2 |$.

We have

$ t_1 - t_2 = \dfrac{-2}{\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) } - \dfrac{1}{\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta) } = \dfrac{ -3 \cos(\theta) +  \sin(\theta) }{\cos(2 \theta)} $

Therefore, we know have two cases:

**Case I**:

$ -3 \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = 2 \cos(2 \theta) $

**Case II**:

$ -3 \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = -2 \cos(\theta) $

The solutions of **Case I** are

$\theta_1 = 0.992125 $ and $ \theta_2 = 4.971958 $

The solutions of **Case II** are

$\theta_3 = 1.830366 $ and $ \theta_4 = 4.133717 $

These four solutions are actually only **two** solutions, because the angles in the second case are separted by $\pi$ from the solutions of the first case.

Hence there are **two** possible lines whose equations are

$ -\sin(\phi_i) (x - 1) + \cos(\phi_i) (y - 1) = 0 $

with $ \phi_1 = 0.992125 $ and $\phi_2 = 1.830366 $